# Trace polynomial from $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $q < p $ be prime numbers. Let $r =ord_p(q)$ the minimal number $v$ s.t $q^v =_p 1$ (considering $q \in (\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^*$)

Let $T: \mathbb{F}_{q^r} \to \mathbb{F}_{q^r}$ be given by $T(X) = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}X^{q^i}$.

In my book they claim that $T$ is surjective onto the subfield $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is this true? Are they saying that $Im(T) \subset \mathbb{F}_q$?

Also that $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$ contains the $p$-$p^{th}$roots of unity and is generated by them as a vector field over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Can you help me see why?

Comment: The phrase "T is surjective onto the subfield $F_q$" is very ugly —specially since the codomain of $T$ is $F_{q^r}$". What is meant is "the image of $T$ is $F_q$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the trace is surjective. Note that $T(a)\in\Bbb F_q$
for $a\in \Bbb F_{q^r}$ (you can prove that by proving $T(a)^q=T(a)$).
For each $b\in \Bbb F_q$, there are at most $q^{r-1}$ elements $a$ with $T(a)=b$
(as $T$ has degree $q^{r-1}$). This is only possible if for each $b\in \Bbb F_q$, there are exactly $q^{r-1}$ elements $a$ in $\Bbb F_{q^r}$ with $T(a)=b$. Thus $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Alternatively, the map is not identically zero because the polynomial would haev too many roots and additive, so the image is a subgroup of $F_q$, of which there are not many. (This is the same argument in different form, but makes it more obvious that all elements in the image have the same number of preimages!)

Comment: Thank you! I was missing $T(a)^q = T(a)$ - need to verify this indeed.